# How to find all accumulation points of a sequence

Tags: limits, sequence-of-function

First of all, I had I apology for snipping the equation out from my worksheet instead of writing it down. I'm new here.

[sequence I need to find all accumulation points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Nnt0.png)

I tried to solve it by hand, by substituting some numbers for n, but I was unable to find any pattern. Therefore, I decided to enter this on graphing calculator, hoping the graph makes it easier to find its accumulation points.
However, I'm not sure why, but my graph didn't show any graph. I also tried putting it in online graphing calculator on google, and it said the bound is out of range.

Therefore, I 'm really stuck now. Not sure what to do, what else I can try.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Ignore the constants in the fraction as they do not matter at infinity and see what you get